# Error while printing in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm Getting the following error while printing in WPF.

> PrintTicket provider failed to retrieve PrintCapabilities. Win32
>   error.

Here is my Code to Print

```
printDlg.PrintDocument(idpSource.DocumentPaginator, "Hello WPF Printing.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is exactly the problem, but something related to Printer.

From Control Panel -> Printers & Fax

1. Right Click the Printer and take Printer preferences
2. Change the Source property to 'Manual Feed'& Apply.(Initially it was'AutoSelect')
3. Still got some error.
4. Again me changed the Source property back to 'Auto Select'& Apply.
5. Changed the Quick set Property to 'Defaults'& Apply

Now its Working Fine

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot